# Create quad from texture and screen metrics

Tags: opengl-es2, mathematics

If I have a texture with known metrics (pixel size, byte type) and a GL surface to render to of a know density and measures, and I want to draw a quad composed of two triangles that correspond to the size of the texture in proportion to the size of the surface. For that I need to recalculate the needed quad's vertexes. Can someone explain me the math involved in this process?

Example: I have a screen/surface of 800x600 and a texture of 100x20 that I want to position in (20, 20). How do I calculate the vertex of the quad needed for it.

My shaders are simple

v

```
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
attribute vec2 a_position;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
   gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0);
   v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
};
```

f

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
};
```

And the VAs even simpler

```
float squareCoords[] = {
     -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
      1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
      1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f
};

char drawOrder[] = {
      0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3
};

float textureCoords[] = {
      0.0f, 1.0f,
      0.0f, 0.0f, 
      1.0f, 0.0f, 
      1.0f, 1.0f
};
```

Comment: What is the **"GL surface(density, measures"**)? Is it a OpenGL texture? Also where do you want to apply quad? maybe you instead want to apply a texture on your quad? Or you want to render something and then have it as a texture?

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to ask maybe you need to rephrase your question so people can help you.

Comment: edited the question to be clearer

Comment: well I see, you don't need to do what you are asking for. you need to understand how texture coordinates actually works.

Comment: Can you please explain it then?

Comment: You want to draw a texture that covers exact (100x20) pixels in a given texture (e.x. screen) or you want your texture to cover an area that is equal to (800x600)/(100x20) = 0.004 of your screen area ?

Comment: The latest. I already have a texture of a given size and I want to create a polygon containing it that I can position and manipulate around the screen.